# Construct Profile Picture URL

Tags: foursquare

Most social apis have a way to construct a url to the user's profile picture using their user_id or username.  Any chance foursquare has something similar or plans to?

http://graph.facebook.com/702855/picture

http://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image/akdotcom.png

Comment: oh yeah... uhm, we were going to add that. Dusting off an old internal thread....

Comment: i am facing the same problem is there any way for doing it in Foursquare...

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem.

Since the last update (changes from June 9th) every user's pic can be constructed via an api call: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=users/self

which returns something like this:

```
photo: {
    prefix: "https://irs3.4sqi.net/img/user/"
    suffix: "/HBVX4T2WQOGG20FE.png"
}
```

Take the two parts and put e.g. 'original' between them:

```
[prefix]/original/[suffix]
```

which gives you the url to the profile pic: https://irs3.4sqi.net/img/user/original/HBVX4T2WQOGG20FE.png

Answer (score 1):

foursquare provides the URL prefix and suffix, example:

```
photo: {
  prefix: "https://irs3.4sqi.net/img/user/"
  suffix "/21325770-GWARVMMU2R5QLN04.jpg"
}
```

you can mount it as follows:

```
[prefix]/original/[suffix] -> for original image
[prefix]/200/[suffix] -> for squared 200x200 image
[prefix]/200x100/[suffix] -> for 200x100 image
```

exemple

```
https://irs3.4sqi.net/img/user/200/21325770-GWARVMMU2R5QLN04.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

At this time, there's no way to construct a profile photo from just the username/user ID.

Comments on this question by Akshay indicate that they might some day support this.

I'm answering here to get this off of the "unanswered" list.